# In KDE the cursor is always huge after rotating screens even when settings is not resolution dependent

Tags: kde, cursor

I recently changed my monitors to be vertical instead of horizontal and since then the cursor is huge.  To be clear I specifically mean the cursor not the pointer.  [image: Here's what I'm talking about]

The pointer is adjusting to the settings under cursor theme, it is really just the cursor that is bothering me.  The link following cursor is also too large but that one isn't as much of a pain as the cursor.  Any idea how to get the cursor to respect the size setting?

Answer (score 1):

I was on Kubuntu 16.04 and I just updated to 18.04 and that seemed to fix the issue.